# How to markup explanatory text in HTML5?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I have some content which is written completely in a non-English (Turkish) language. (So, I have `<html lang="tr">` on the top.) Within the text, I am using some *terms* in that language. I want to add some "semi-visual" content for such a term that will give its English equivalent (using the `title` attribute probably), in case the reader wants to know the exact English equivalent of the *term* (probably by moving their mouse pointer over the *term*).

The `<dfn>` tag is not appropriate for this purpose, because most of the times I will not be defining the *term* in its ancestor element; I will be just using it. A simple alternative would be to enclose the *term* within a `<span>` element with a `title` attribute containing the English equivalent of the *term*. For example,

```
bla bla bla <span title="format">biçim</span> bla bla bla...
```

Here "`format`" is the English equivalent of the non-English term "`biçim`".

Please note that, in most of the cases, I will not want the *term* to be rendered differently than the text around it.

What is the best HTML5 markup to implement such a semantic need?

Comment: If you use the `title` attribute, the browser will automatically render a tooltip. It sounds like you want to actually modify the term in place?

Comment: The tooltip displayed by using the `title` attribute of a tag is  OK for me (although it cannot be used in mobile devices); and I do not want to modify the _term_ inplace. My question is about which HTML5 tag is more appropriate (semantically) than a simple `<span>` tag.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an exact tag specific for this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element#inline_text_semantics (MAYBE bdi if the translation could be rtl instead of ltr)

Answer (score 2):

Provide a separate dictionary (probably after the main text) as a `DL`/`DT`/`DD` list and refer to corresponding `DT`/`DD` pairs from the main text. If popups are needed, they can be implemented on top of the same static semantic markup. `SPAN` is 100% semantics-less generic element, I wouldn’t use it in this context.